# Unable to type polish characters after upgrade to Ubuntu 18

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, internationalization

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16 LTS to 18 LTS, I can't type in Polish or other international characters. 
Input type is added. Even using onboard keyboard, after clicking Polish characters with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, nothing is typed in.

`xmodmap` output:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *Settings*, *Language and Region*, *Input Sources*.  If the only item in the list is "English (US)", then this is the cause.

Click the "+" button, and -- assuming your keyboard has English US layout, and you type diacritics using modifier keys -- click on **English (United States)**.

> Yes, this is surprisingly counterintuitive. English (US) is precisely the one you are trying to get rid of, so this is the last one you'd pick. Also, it isn't apparent from the UI that a *new selection list* will appear. This needs UI redesign, IMO.

Anyway, a *new list* appears, and from this you can select, for instance, **English (intl. with AltGr dead keys)**.

Once you have selected that, you can remove the **English (US)** input source using the "-" button.  You can use the little button with the keyboard icon to see that the new source has the desired layout.

If diacritics still don't work, then your *AltGr* key may be remapped. In *Settings, Devices, Keyboard* click "Reset All". If you have made any `xmodmap` or `setxkbmap` settings, undo these too.